# How do I check how many versions of Python I have installed on my device using the cmd prompt?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I have Anaconda and Spyder, which I know use Python 3.6.5 and 3.6.6, alongside Python 3.7.0. How do I check how many version of python I have installed using the Windows Command Prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python launcher (`"C:\WINDOWS\py.exe"`) has a list command: `py.exe -0` It displays all installed python versions. If all you want is a visual list, that works alone. In a batch script, however, you might want to count the versions:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set pyvcount=0
for /f %%G in ('%SYSTEMROOT%\py.exe -0') do set /a pyvcount+=1
```

Unfortunately, the I cannot figure out how to stop the command from printing `Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows` to the console.

**EDIT:**
Hide the output by redirecting error stream to nul

```
for /f %%G in ('%SYSTEMROOT%\py.exe -0 2>nul') do set /a pyvcount+=1
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me in a `.bat` file on Windows 7. Displays three lines, first is `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`, second is `set pyvcount=0`, last is just `-0') was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: Got it to work in a batch script by changing the last line to: `for /f %%G in ('%SYSTEMROOT%\py.exe -0') do set /a pyvcount+=1` Also had to add a `echo Number of installed Pythons: %pyvcount%` line at the very end to see the final value of `pyvcount`.

Comment: You can hide the line output by adding `@echo off` in the beginning. It won't affect the `echo` command. I also fixed the `for` loop. My mistake.